# Is there a way to request the values ​of all inputs on the page without having to call one by one in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to request all the inputs of the page and then send it by e-mail... But as there are many, is there any way to call everyone without creating too many variables?

Obs: as I am a beginner in php, if you can show me an example I will be grateful.

Here´s the code i'm working with:

```
<?php

require  'email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$recipient = $_POST['emailFor'];
$sender = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


//I mean this part:

$results_SRV_AA_A10Name = $_POST['result-SRV-AA-A10-name'];
$results_SRV_AA_A10Email = $_POST['result-SRV-AA-A10-email'];
$results_SRV_AA_A10Tel = $_POST['result-SRV-AA-A10-tel'];
$results_SRV_AA_A11 = $_POST['result-SRV-AA-A11'];
$results_SRV_AA_A12 = $_POST['result-SRV-AA-A12'];
$results_SRV_AA_A13 = $_POST['result-SRV-AA-A13'];
etc....

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail ->isSMTP();
$mail ->Host = '***********';
$mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail ->Username = '*************';
$mail ->Password = '*************';
$mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail ->Port = 465;

$mail->addReplyTo($sender);
$mail ->setFrom('**********', 'Stack Overflow');
$mail ->addAddress($recipient);
$mail->Subject = "$sender send you this";

$mail ->isHTML(true);
$mail ->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail ->Body .="

$AllVariables

";

if(!$mail ->send()){
    echo "Erro no envio do e-mail, tente em instantes<br>";
    echo $mail ->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Mensagem enviada</title>
        <script>alert('Enviada com sucesso');</script>
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; index.html'>
        </head>
        <body></body>
        </html>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to dump all of the `$_POST` values as newline-separated values:

```
$post = implode("\n", $_POST);
$mail->Body .= "\n{$post}\n";
// eg:
// John Doe
// john.doe@email.com
// 555-5555
// ...
```

If you want the field name included as well:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $mail->Body .= "{$key}: {$value}\n";
}
// eg:
// result-SRV-AA-A10-name: John Doe
// result-SRV-AA-A10-email: john.doe@email.com
// result-SRV-AA-A10-tel: 555-5555
// ...
```

Of course don't forget to sanitize/escape your user-provided data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this function to do this for you:

```
extract($_POST);
```

After this, keys in the associated array will be the variable!
And there's a point, use _ instead of - for fields names.

Comment: Be very careful with this though, see [extract][1] docs, especially the warnings.


  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Is it ok to use with POST method? In this manual, they advise to be careful only with $_GET and $_FILES

Comment: @VitorFreitas `$_POST` is user input as well, so no. In the first warning, it says ***e.g.***, so was only listing a few examples. In the second warning, under Notes, it says `etc.`, so not just those two.